# mprof run <executable> gets me "Command not found"

Tags: python-3.x, memory-profiling

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3. I have installed `memory_profiler` using the following command:

`pip3 install -U memory_profiler`

I was able to run `python3 -m memory_profiler <executable>` from the command line with no issues. However, if I try `mprof run <executable>` I get the following output:

```
Command 'mprof' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gprof' from deb binutils
  command 'pprof' from deb tau
  command 'mlprof' from deb mlton-tools
  command 'sprof' from deb libc-dev-bin
  command 'prof' from deb profphd

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I am following the steps in the documentation of `memory_profiler` [here](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) but it's not working. Is there any extra step given the fact that I use Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make it work is the following. Instead of `mprof run <executable>`, the following works:

`python3 /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mprof.py run <executable>`

You must replace `myuser` with the appropriate value. Your full path may differ. You need to find where is `mprof.py`. The general command is: `python3 /full/path/to/mprof.py run <executable>`.